# openssl_decrypt fails. cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes

Tags: php, encryption

I have a decryption function that just started failing for unknown reasons. The error is "openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is only 6 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes". I  have found multiple suggestions to "add base64 encoding", which I already had.

My function is

```
function decryptThis($data) {
    $encryptionKey = "encryptionKey";
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($encryptionKey);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = array_pad(explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2),2,null);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'AES-128-CTR', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
}
```

Comment: `decryptThis()` expects the data in a specific (inefficient) format: *Base64(Base64(<ciphertext>)::<iv>)*. Maybe `$data` does not have the correct format or the IV is really too short. The question can actually only be answered if you post some test data or the encryption code.

Answer (score 0):

Previously a lot of the mcrypt and OpenSSL functions simply right padded the IV with zeros. However nowadays we try and keep to the specifications for the cipher / mode of operation. If you want to return to the previous situation then you'll have to right pad yourself.

It seems that the fix was a bit too generic or that the author was a bit overzealous as CTR really doesn't take an IV but a *nonce*. In that sense it would be perfectly reasonable to right-pad a nonce with zeros, as long as the key / nonce combination remains unique.

However, many CTR (counter mode) implementations assume that you provide an entire block consisting of the nonce + starting counter value.

---

Note that OpenSSL is a C library, so just providing an IV value of 6 bytes would result in a buffer overrun, possibly leading to broken - or worse: irreversible - encryption.